# Connecting kaspersky db via SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Kaspersky db is accessible in local machine via SQL Server Management Studio by Windows and SQL Server accounts.

But in network and from another machine I ran into problem, the problem is there is two database instances on that machine, one named default instance as local and one as local\KAV_CS_ADMIN_KIT.

I can connect to default instance from another machine on local network setting server name as Ip of machine but for second db (kaspersky db) when I use

```
servername:192.168.0.15\KAV_CS_ADMIN_KIT (ip of hostmachine)
```

I ran into a network related or instance-specific error occurred.

Comment: try adding port number(you can see that ,using sql server configuration manager) and ensure sql server browser service is running